# SharePoint 2010 user.aspx problem

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

I have SharePoint 2010 and I have a problem with one item in my list. Every other item are OK.

When I choose this specific item and trying to see "Item Permissions"

[image]

it redirect me to page where is

> "Error"... _layouts/User.aspx?obj={F651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E4
>   ......

[image]

I cannot do anything with this item because I do not have permissions for this item, but my account is in "site collection administrator" so I should have everything permissions which I need :( Is there any way to set the permissions?

there is some errors from log:

```
09/19/2016 14:14:32.83  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:https://****/ap/zadanky/_layouts/User.aspx?obj=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D,18012,LISTITEM&List=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D&Source=****%2Fap%2Fzadanky%2FLists%2FZadanky%2FAllItems%2Easpx)

09/19/2016 14:14:32.84  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/ap/zadanky    ba60f793-6ca7-4062-b39d-a6a2255b2491

09/19/2016 14:14:32.89  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  Document Management Server      Document Management             52od    Medium  MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/User.aspx?obj=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D,18012,LISTITEM&List=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D&Source=****%2Fap%2Fzadanky%2FLists%2FZadanky%2FAllItems%2Easpx].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list. ba60f793-6ca7-4062-b39d-a6a2255b2491


09/19/2016 14:14:32.92  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High    The action could not be completed. Please try again.    ba60f793-6ca7-4062-b39d-a6a2255b2491


09/19/2016 14:14:32.92  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  SharePoint  Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The action could not be completed. Please try again.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetSecurityInfo(String bstrUrl, String bstrObjUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt64& pEffectivePermMask, Boolean& pbHasUniquePerm, String& pbstrPermUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSecurityInfo(String bstrUrl, String bstrObjUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt64& pEffectivePermMask, Boolean& pbHasUniquePerm, String& pbstrPermUrl) ba60f793-6ca7-4062-b39d-a6a2255b2491


09/19/2016 14:14:32.94  w3wp.exe (****:0x2D80)          0x129C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:https://****/ap/zadanky/_layouts/User.aspx?obj=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D,18012,LISTITEM&List=%7BF651FCCB-B580-43D4-BD12-AE51A3E43369%7D&Source=****%2Fap%2Fzadanky%2FLists%2FZadanky%2FAllItems%2Easpx)). Execution Time=104,604356140236    ba60f793-6ca7-4062-b39d-a6a2255b2491
```